# Google maps api v2 | Store Finder/Locator

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have a web page called 'Store Locator' that uses Google maps api v2. It all works very well when you are on this page but I would like to add a sidebar form input that would allow users on other pages of the site to be able to enter an address, and then be forwarded to the 'Store Locator' page, with their map/results displayed.

So my question is this: How do I amend the code below in order to be able to send the form/location data to the maps api from any page on my site and get the results on my store locator page?

Any help greatfully appreciated as this is driving me crazy! S. (Code below; I have omitted the api key part, the body onload stuff and the xml/php processing)

*map code*

```
var map;
var geocoder;

var iconN = new GIcon(); 
iconN.image = 'images/marker.png';
iconN.iconSize = new GSize(33, 12);
iconN.iconAnchor = new GPoint(28, 43);
iconN.infoWindowAnchor = new GPoint(65, 12);

function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
    geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById('map'));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(53.2415, -1.6809), 4);
  }
}
function searchLocations() {     
    var address = document.getElementById('addressInput').value;
    geocoder.getLatLng(address, function(latlng) {
    if (!latlng) {
        alert(address + ' not found');
    } else {
    searchLocationsNear(latlng);         
    }
    }); 
}
function searchLocationsNear(center) {
    var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
    var searchUrl = 'xml/phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
    GDownloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
        var xml = GXml.parse(data);
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        map.clearOverlays();
        var results = document.getElementById('results');
        results.innerHTML = '';
        if (markers.length == 0) {
            results.innerHTML = '<div>No results found.</div>';
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(53.2415, -1.6809), 4);
        return;
    }

    var bounds = new GLatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute('name');
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute('address');
        var distance = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('distance'));
        var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('lat')),
                                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute('lng')));
        var phone = markers[i].getAttribute('phone');
        var website = markers[i].getAttribute('website');
        var logo = markers[i].getAttribute('logo');

        var marker = createMarker(point, name, address, phone, website, logo);
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        var sidebarEntry = createSidebarEntry(marker, name, address, distance, phone, website, logo);
        results.appendChild(sidebarEntry);
        bounds.extend(point);
    }
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter(), map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
    });
}

function createMarker(point, name, address, phone) {
  var marker = new GMarker(point, iconN);
  var html = '<strong>' + name + '</strong> <br/>' + address + '<br />Tel: ' + phone;
  GEvent.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
  });
  return marker;
}

function createSidebarEntry(marker, name, address, distance, phone, website, logo) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    var html = '<img src="images/stockist-logos/' + logo + '" height="102" alt="' + name + '" class="right" /> <h3>' + name + '</h3> <small>Distance: <strong>' + distance.toFixed(1) + ' miles</strong></small><br/><p>' + address + '</p><p>Tel: ' + phone + '</p>';    
    div.innerHTML = html;      
    GEvent.addDomListener(div, 'click', function() {
        GEvent.trigger(marker, 'click');
    });
    GEvent.addDomListener(div, 'mouseover', function() {
        div.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    });
    GEvent.addDomListener(div, 'mouseout', function() {
        div.style.backgroundColor = '#f7f7f7';
    });
    return div;   
}
```

*form/html code*

```
<form action="#" id="stockists" onsubmit="searchLocations()">
<label>Location: </label><input type="text" id="addressInput" />
<label>Distance (miles): </label>
<select id="radiusSelect">
<option value="25" selected>25 </option>
<option value="100">100 </option>                        
<option value="200">200 </option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />     
</form>
```

Comment: why not use a small form on the side of the page that posts to your maps page, and have the map page process the querystring values

Comment: thanks - how would i do that then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place a form on the side of your main content, make the form post/get to your processing page

```
<form action="posting_page.php" method="get" id="stockists">
<label>Location: </label><input type="text" id="addressInput" />
<label>Distance (miles): </label>
<select id="radiusSelect">
<option value="25" selected>25 </option>
<option value="100">100 </option>                        
<option value="200">200 </option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

then use php or javascript to get the querystring/form values

```
function searchLocations() {     
    var address = <GETFROMPHP>;
    geocoder.getLatLng(address, function(latlng) {
    if (!latlng) {
        alert(address + ' not found');
    } else {
    searchLocationsNear(<GETFROMPHP>);         
    }
    }); 
}
```

php is not my primary development language so you'll need to look up how to get the querystring/form values. You could also set the input fields on your processing page to the values from the post/get so you wouldn't have to change your script. Let me know if you need more help